# Watershed issue

Tags: grass-gis, error, watershed, memory, catchment

I am attempting to create a catchment of Danube.

So far I have used the r.fill.dir to create a depressionless map and flow directions. Thus, I am now looking to use r.watershed to create stream segments and drainage directions.

I have used the depressionless map as input, chose 100,000 as minimum and 10,000 as maximum values respectively. Additionally, I unchecked every post except stream segments and drainage directions. These have been assigned paths as well.

After running the tool I get this error message;

[image]

I tried increasing the maximum memory allowed for the process, but I keep getting the same error message.

Anybody know how to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

First, for the GRASS module `r.watershed` there is no need to fill depressions. The routing algorithm works fine delineating streams thru real depressions.

Now, in order to answer the memory issue, we need to know the region settings. So please enter at the command prompt `g.region -p` and post the output.

What are the 10,000 and 100,000 values referring to? (what is minimum and maximum?)

Comment: projection: 3 (Latitude-Longitude)
zone:       0
datum:      wgs84
ellipsoid:  wgs84
north:      90N
south:      90S
west:       180W
east:       180E
nsres:      1
ewres:      1
rows:       180
cols:       360
cells:      64800

the min and max values are from the watershed tool. They represent the minimum size of exterior watershed basin and maximum length of surface flow.

Comment: If I understand, you're trying to delineate watersheds for the whole world, working at a resolution 1 degree X 1 degree. So a total of 64800 pixels. And you're setting the min basin size at 10,000. So you'll be dividing the world into about 6 basins total? The malloc error in your post indicates that the process could not allow 1.3 GB of memory. That should not happen with these region settings. What is the resolution of the DEM you are using? (run `r.info` on the DEM)

Comment: BTW, the Danube is a large river, but the drainage area is much smaller than 10,000 sq degrees... It's about 800,000 sq km, so about 7 sq degrees.

Comment: Sorry for the late replies, working on some other projects as well.
I am fairly new to QGIS and especially working on watershed calculations. I tried some values I found in an article, but they might not make sence in this case. Should I alter the min- and max values?

Additionally, how do I run the command prompt on a DEM? I assume you run it in Grass, but I have never used the program before.

Comment: I like to use GRASS on its own, from the command prompt. But that's a matter of personal preference. I think you need to first determine what coordinate system the original DEM is projected in. (I doubt that it is Long/Lat) and what the units are. Then you choose the minimum basin size as the **number of pixels** that make up your desired basin. And before trying to run r.watershed, you must (like in all GRASS modules) set the region to match your study area.

Comment: @PetterChristensen many commands work in QGIS as fine as directly in GRASS, but you need to know a bit what the cmmand atempt, otherwise you might end doing something far inteded.

Comment: You can create a single catchent with [r.water.outlet](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/r.water.outlet.html) but first you an input from [r.watershed](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/r.watershed.html), the flow direction raster map. In the last command, the minimum refer to the "minimum size of an exterior watershed basin in cells", which is not relevant for a single catchment area, but you need a value there. The maximum probably refers to the "Maximum length of surface flow in map units" for RUSLE calculations, is it part of you interest?

Comment: Alright, I'll read up on the commands and see if I can figure this out. Thank you guys, think I have what I need then :)